# OpenVPN installation issue on windows

Tags: installation, openvpn

When I was trying to install OpenVPN, it always tells me "The installation cannot continue as OpenVPN is currently running. Please close all OpenVPN instances and re-run the installer." I also tried to do the same thing on my friends computer, got the same result. I checked the Task Manage, I can see any OpenVPN process in running.

I googled this issue, it looks no one have this problem besides me.

Wish someone could help me with it.

Comment: If you run `services.msc` is the OpenVPN service running?

Comment: I checked it out, and I am sure there is not an OpenVPN service running. This is my first time downloading OpenVPN to this PC.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you don't have another process running with name "opnevpn.exe"....e.g. your own custom installation script/program.

It seems OpenVPN's installation package will check for a process by that name and give an error if it find one.

Comment: For me it was the `ExpressVPN` service causing the issue. It runs `OpenVPN` under the hood.